# How and when to make dua in sujud?

Tags: salat

I would like to make dua in sujud to ask Allah and thank Allah (basically talk to Allah of my situations in life).

Is dua in sujud in fard prayer ok? And which rakaa should I do sujud dua in? The last rakaa?

Do I go down in sujud and say "sobhana rabbi al alla"(3 times) and then pause for 3 seconds and then say my dua? And after I say tashahod/salam?